# How to convert a float (fraction of minutes) to timedelta in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I would like to interpolate a signal that was measured in minutes:  `1 ~= 1 min`  and `1.5 ~= 1min 30s`. I would like to convert that to something timelike and see if the interpolation method works better.

My Series looks like:

```
retentionTime
0.066     2447
3.888     3357
4.061     3988
4.087     5143
4.381     4440
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The index can be converted to minutes using `pandas.to_timedelta()`:

```
chrom.index = pd.to_timedelta(chrom.index, unit='minutes')
```